# Actors in Azure service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, stateful-actor-service

How to use Azure service fabric Actors in a different language (python or Go) to build stateful microservices? Or are they limited to Java/C# ?

Comment: They are limited for the moment to java/c#, correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are limited in JavaC# for now
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/samples/service-fabric-java-getting-started/